# Creating a hash MD5 of a XML File

Tags: c#, xml, validation, hash, md5

I am having troubles when trying to calculate the hash MSD5 of an XML file.
I have a third party validator that calculates it correctly, i am trying to make my own validator in c# but it does not work, i keep getting an invalid hash MD5 with big xml files, with small files it works fine. The big file has around 63000 lines.

The code in C#:

```
public string GenerateHash(string xml, string hashOrigin = null)
    {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        string pKeyEncode = doc.Root.Value;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hashOrigin))
            pKeyEncode = pKeyEncode.Replace(hashOrigin, "");

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider _cs = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] _bs = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(pKeyEncode);
        _bs = _cs.ComputeHash(_bs);
        StringBuilder _s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte _b in _bs)
        {
            _s.Append(_b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }
        int a = _s.GetHashCode();
        return _s.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Isolate the bytes you are feeding to `ComputeHash` and compare them against what you're doing in your Delphi program. We can't debug this for you.

Comment: the hash of the C# is different from the validator, when i try a smaller file it works fine, a large file not.

Comment: Quite unclear what you have problem with... But one of standard issues with signing XML is normalization - it may be good idea to split code into 2 parts (normalization of XML and hashing resulting string) and debug each separately to verify each produces result you need.

Comment: thats the problem the delphi program is a third party. I dont have access to the program source code.

Comment: Alexander, the hashing works excellent on the small file, when i try a big one it fails, i tried other functions that i found on the web, and i keep getting the same wrong result.

Comment: Log the bytes that go into each on a large file and play "spot the difference".

Comment: Have you tried `XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)`?

Comment: Yes, just tried, didnt work...thanks anyway,

Comment: Why "ISO-8859-1"?  XML supports unicode encoding, so `Encoding.UTF8` seems more natural.

Comment: Most cryptographic hashes and signatures on XML files require that the XML be [canonicalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML) first. You may want to verify what that other library is doing.

Comment: its a fair question, tried this, did not work.. thanks anyway.

Comment: [MD5 is broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). This means two different files, under the right circumstances, could give the same hash. I suggest you use a different hashing algorithm.

Comment: I have to use MD5 the file is padronized by the government, i agree with but laws are laws unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure about `doc.Root.Value` as the subject? It ignores all tags, attributes etc. Can you post a small XML for which it does work?

Comment: Yes, its part of the normalization of the hash only the content of tags, a smal xml its about 1560 lines sorry.

Comment: Can you share a sample XML file that works, and a sample that doesn't? We're just guessing here.

Comment: dbc I cant, this file contains financial data of the organization that i work, wish i could.

Comment: Don't need to post real data, just XML containing junk data that happens to produce different MD5 hashes.  Perhaps, in making the synthetic test case, you'll spot something that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I will preface this with the statement that you should never try to implement your own security methods unless you know exactly what you are doing. Even the smallest error can create security holes that make your function worthless. That being said, microsoft has MD5 functionality build into `System.Security`. Here is an even easy way to do MD5:

```
var xmlBytes = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(xmlAsString);
var hashedXmlBytes = ((HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("MD5")).ComputeHash(xmlBytes);
var hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedXmlBytes);
```

I would not recommend using MD5, it has been computationally insecure for some time now. If this is academic, then you are probably okay. Otherwise, at the bare minimum I would recommend using the above code with "SHA512" and salting it first. The current recommended algorithms are actually bcrypt or PBKDF2. These run a certain amount of times in a row (which you set), meaning you can force the hash to take a certain amount of time. This means people brute forcing or creating precomputed tables (rainbow tables) will have to wait a certain penalty time in order to compute each value, drastically increasing the security. Using SHA512, you increase the amount of solutions possible for a brute force and make it require large amounts of storage for precomputed tables, but computations are still fast and storage is considered "cheap".

Comment: Did not work, just read something about a max size of string builder...       https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The Brazilian government dictates that the hash must be MD5... cant change.

Comment: It must be before or during the actual hashing, because in md5 there is truncation and the output will only ever be 32 characters. From what I have read the default max capacity is the same as Int32, that is 2,147,483,647. Each character is 8 bits, so your xml needs to have less than 268,435,455 characters if you are going to serialize it to use. It shouldn't have issues with max size otherwise.

Comment: the xml has around 3000000 characters, thats not it...

Comment: What error did it get when it told you it didn't work and what line did you get the error (out of the ones posted)?

Comment: I just get a Hash Md5 that is not correct.

Comment: If you used the above code, then you received a hash md5 code which is correct, but doesn't match your other code. There is only one correct specification for md5, which means that what you are comparing it to is either incorrect or not md5. At this point I would look into what was suggested above and below and check for special characters and things that may be making the binary different before hashing.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, i am gonna try with another language, maybe Delphi or C++, dont know yet, thanks anyway.

Comment: So it turns out there's a way to do it in 1 line. :-) FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(string, "MD5"),

Answer (score -1):

If you want an MD5 hash, you can simply do this, but it looks like there's some other stuff going on with what you're trying. For example, you're calling .GetHashCode() and considering that an MD5 hash, but .GetHashCode() isn't an MD5 hash.

If you're using .GetHashCode() you may as well cut all the MD5 stuff out and just do this:

```
public string GenerateHash(string xml)
{
   return xml.GetHashCode().ToString();
}
```

However, .GetHashCode() is .NET-specific, so it wouldn't translate to an equivalent value with the Delphi program.

Otherwise, for the true MD5 hash, you can do something like this.

Swiped from:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx

```
public string GenerateHash(string xml)
{
  //you can potentially do something to standardize the format of the XML here.

  // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
  MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
  byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
  byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

  // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
  {
      sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

EDIT: There's also a 1-line version (if anyone is curious in the future).

```
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(string, "MD5"),
```

Comment: I tried this function before, it keeps returning the wrong hash.

Comment: i am begininng to think that is a limitation of the language maybe...

Comment: Modified to change `input` to `xml`

Comment: It will return a correct MD5 hash. If it's "wrong" to you, then you may want to play around with encoding or do something like standardize whitespace. It's certainly not a "limitation of the language" at any rate.